# Removing field wrapper in a form

Tags: forms

I would like to theme a form, and the div wrapping my text input element prevents me from doing what i want. So i got this right now :

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-email">
 <input type="text" id="edit-email" name="email" value="mail@msn.com" size="20" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have this :

```
 <input type="text" id="edit-email" name="email" value="mail@msn.com" size="20" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set [`#theme_wrappers`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#theme_wrappers) of the element to empty array so the element will not have any wrapper at all.

```
$form['email']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
```

Comment: this worked for form element like textfield but not worked for textarea, do you know how can I get ride off  from wrappers in coment body ?

Comment: @zhilevan it should remove wrapper of textarea, but the system's textarea will add `div` between the wrapper and the textarea itself, mainly use for handling resizable textarea. If you don't need the resizable or you have custom handler for it, you can override [`theme_textarea`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_textarea/7) to get rid of the `div`.

Comment: Great. This works for the text box in the form. But does not works for buttons it seems. I tried `$form['actions']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();` and `$form['actions']['submit']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();` for the search block form.

Comment: Saved my day! @siddiq For form buttons you need to add a template suggestion and then change HTML there. More: http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2017/01/28/adding-twig-template-suggestions-for-form-elements